# how to use Prolog with J2EE for develop web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, swi-prolog

I am trying to develop the Web Application with Prolog, But SWI-Prolog is not supported with Java for a Web application. 
Please suggest some other Prolog IDE's for web development.

When I am using SWI-Prolog in J2EE application (Web application), It works only for one instance because it is a desktop application if I open my localhost in other browser or private browsing, it shows error and throws exception

Comment: Recommendations for tools are offtopic, but maybe you get answers anyway. In that case it might be good to elaborate what JavaEE has to do with the question.

Comment: When I am using SWI-Prolog in J2EE application (Web application), It works only for one instance because it is a desktop application if I open my localhost in other browser or private browsing, it shows error and throws exception

Comment: @LokeshVerma: I recommend incorporating your last comment into your original question.  That talks more to the error that you are attempting to address.